# Unexpected 'INDENT' in CoffeeScript Example Code

Tags: coffeescript

As I was playing around for the first time with CoffeeScript, I ran in to a problem.  In order to debug my problem, I tried replacing my whole file with one of the example bits of code from the coffee script site:

```
kids =
  brother:
    name: "Max"
    age:  11
  sister:
    name: "Ida"
    age:  9
```

However, when I try to compile that code, I get:

```
Error: In coffee/main.coffee, Parse error on line 3: Unexpected 'INDENT'
    at Object.parseError (/usr/lib/coffeescript/parser.js:501:11)
    at Object.parse (/usr/lib/coffeescript/parser.js:573:32)
    at Object.compile (/usr/lib/coffeescript/coffee-script.js:23:22)
    at /usr/lib/coffeescript/command.js:99:27
    at /usr/lib/coffeescript/command.js:72:28
    at fs:84:13
    at node.js:773:9
In coffee/main.coffee, Parse error on line 3: Unexpected 'INDENT'
```

Since this is code from the CoffeeScript site, I assume the code itself isn't the problem.  However, the compiler also seems to be working properly; if I compile:

```
a = 2
```

it generates a file with:

```
(function(){
  var a;
  a = 2;
})();
```

as expected.  So in other words, the code is good, the compiler is good, and yet somehow I'm getting this Unexpected 'IDENT' error ... can anyone help me understand what is going on?

Comment: Always try pasting your code into http://coffeescript.org/#try: to see if the error occurs in the latest CoffeeScript release.

Comment: I've had that similar error when i forget something in the previous line, so it is not expecting the code to be indented

Answer (score 73, accepted):

I am pretty sure this is a tabs-vs-spaces issue. Tell your editor not to convert spaces to tabs if it does that. Also, go through your code with the cursor and make sure it doesn't jump over blank areas.

The issue is that while normal editors see a tab as equivalent to two or four spaces, coffeescript sees it as one space, so the indentation gets messed up.

If this all doesn't help, make sure you have a recent coffeescript version, e.g. 1.1.0 or newer.

Comment: I've triple-checked my whitespace (using Eclipse's show whitespace characters feature), and re-done them with both spaces and tabs; I still get the same exact error.  As for having a new coffeescript, I got whatever version comes in the Ubuntu package ... looks like ... 0.7.0!  That might be my problem, let me try installing coffee manually and see if that helps.

Comment: this goes to show that ubuntu's packaging and updating model is problematic in areas like NodeJS and CoffeeScript that are evolving so fast. i recommend installing the latest stable NodeJS from http://nodejs.org/download/ and then simply do `npm install coffee-script`. IMHO using `sudo apt-get install whatever-node-module` feels downright wrong; npm is definitely the better tool for the task at hand. did you know that CoffeeScript 1.0.0 was released on christmas 2010? that's three years ago.

Answer (score 11):

If you are using a JetBrains IDE (IntelliJ, PHPStorm, etc) the change of setting that worked for me is:

> File > Settings > Project Settings > Code Style > CoffeeScript > Tabs
>   and Indents

Tick "Use tab character" & "Smart tabs"

Comment: There's no reason I should be forced to use tabs.  Turned out my error is related to code below being incorrectly indented.

Comment: changed the wording to avoid misunderstanding of being forced to have this setting.

Answer (score 4):

Code is fine. Make sure you haven't messed up the whitespace (strange control chars showing as blanks, tabs or similar).

Comment: Thanks, but I tried turning whitespace characters on in Eclipse and I can see that they actually are spaces.  Just to be safe I tried deleting and replacing all of the indentation, both with spaces (two per indent level) and with tabs.  In all cases I get the same error :-(

Comment: Thanks, it turned out it was the version.  @*#$@&*#! out-of-date repositories ...

Comment: @machineghost: He didn't mention the version. I did. :(

Answer (score 0):

If you have the same problem, but your indentation is okay,
then you must be suffering from [bug 2868](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/2868).

Basically, the error is misleading. Check for indentation
errors **in the `require`d files**.

Answer (score 0):

When in Atom you can automatically convert tabs to spaces:

`Packages > Whitespace > Convert Tabs to Spaces`

Answer (score -1):

You can resolve this two ways
1. IF using webstorm File->Default Settings  as said above
2. Other workaround, is to use a different editor like Sublime, there u can press enter on earlier line and it will auto tab it for you with spaces