# Fail assets compile when deploying to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, coffeescript, asset-pipeline

I want to deploy my Rails app to heroku but assets compile fails. In local environment, it works well.

```
       Your bundle is complete! It was installed into ./vendor/bundle
       Cleaning up the bundler cache.
-----> Writing config/database.yml to read from DATABASE_URL
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       rake aborted!
       Error: Parse error on line 13: Unexpected 'INDENT'
       (in /tmp/build_iztv4ybnwpqh/app/assets/javascripts/require_dir/view_after
_key_recieve.js.coffee)
```

Log says there is unexpected indent on line 13, but I cannot find any error.

```
root = exports ? this
class root.ViewAfterKeyRecieveViewModel
  constructor: ->
    @isDecoded = ko.observable false
    @encryptedKey = ko.observable ''
    @personalPassword = ko.observable ''
    @decodePassword = ''

    # do when @personalPassword is changed
    ko.computed =>
      if @personalPassword() isnt ''
        @decodePassword = sjcl.decrypt(@personalPassword(), @encryptedKey())
      simg = new ScrambledImage044 "/assets/image61.png" # THIS IS LINE 13
        height: 16
        width:  12
        canvasId: 'original'
        seed:   @decodePassword
      simg.fix()
      simg.paint()

  createEncryptedKey: ->
    # create key and set to @encryptedKey
    @encryptedKey sjcl.encrypt("todo", "hirakegoma")
```

Thank you for your kindness.

Comment: It may be a problem of tabs instead of spaces. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8197466/unexpected-indent-in-coffeescript-example-code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
simg = new ScrambledImage044 "/assets/image61.png",  # notice the comma
    height: 16
    width:  12
    canvasId: 'original'
    seed:   @decodePassword
```

or this :

```
simg = new ScrambledImage044( "/assets/image61.png"
    height: 16
    width:  12
    canvasId: 'original'
    seed:   @decodePassword
) # notice the parens
```

Comment: this is weird indeed. In my experience, there are always pitfalls when compiling coffescript in production environment ; i think that the parser configuration defaults may be more strict (and won't allow some of the synctatic sugars) in this mode, but i can't tell for sure. I once went stark raving mad trying to correct such a bug, just to discover that adding parens solved the issue...