# CoffeeScript compiling: Unexpected IF

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I am writing some CoffeeScript code for an API, and in the error catching section of my code I placed an IF statement.  Now, during the compilation process CoffeeScript is saying that the IF statement was unexpected.

```
#  Handle Errors
app.error (err, req, res, next) ->
    if err instanceof NotFound
        res.send '404, not found.'
    else
        res.send '500, internal server error.'

app.get '/*', (req, res) ->
    throw new NotFound

NotFound = (msg) ->
    this.name = 'NotFound'
    Error.call this, msg
    Error.captureStackTrace this, arguments.callee
```

The error is

```
/home/techno/node/snaprss/application.coffee:22:5: error: unexpected if
    if err instanceOf NotFound
    ^^
```

Does anyone have any ideas where the issue is within my code?

Comment: I have fixed the issue with my errors by using a different method to handle the errors.

Comment: @techo this was probably an indention error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Unexpected 'INDENT' in CoffeeScript Example Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8197466/unexpected-indent-in-coffeescript-example-code)

This issue looks somehow similar.

Consider therefore checking tabs and spaces in your editor.

Answer (score 4):

Another thing to watch out for parenthesis and braces:

Javascript

```
if (condition) {
    //logic
}
```

should be CoffeeScript

```
if condition
    # logic
# END if
```

Answer (score 0):

Watch out for long conditions indentation for example:

```
if condition and other_condition and
yet_another_condition
^^
```

it should be

```
if condition and other_condition and
  yet_another_condition
```

For example Intellij breaks this indentation

Comment: I believe this is incorrect... at least with the most recent version of CoffeeScript

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I did the following:

```coffee
myArray.map (line) -> {
  if a equals ''
    return {}
}
```

The problem was that an arrow function cannot have braces unless returning an object. My solution was to remove the braces:

```coffee
myArray.map (line) ->
  if a equals ''
    return {}
```