# Rails 4: conditional if statement with coffeescript not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, if-statement, coffeescript, conditional-statements

In my Rails app, I have a `Post` model.

I am using coffeescript to make the post form more dynamic.

In `posts.coffee`, I have:

```
$(document).ready ->
  text_max = 140
  $('#character_count').html text_max + ' characters remaining'
  $('#post_short_copy').keyup ->
    text_length = $('#post_short_copy').val().length
    text_remaining = text_max - text_length
    $('#character_count').html text_remaining + ' characters remaining'
    return
  return
```

This works really well.

Now, I need to insert an if statement inside this code, to only execute `$('#character_count').html text_max + ' characters remaining'` if `$('#post_short_copy').is(':empty')`.

I have tried the following code:

```
$(document).ready ->
  text_max = 140
  if $('#post_short_copy').is(':empty') {
    $('#character_count').html text_max + ' characters remaining'
  }
  $('#post_short_copy').keyup ->
    text_length = $('#post_short_copy').val().length
    text_remaining = text_max - text_length
    $('#character_count').html text_remaining + ' characters remaining'
    return
  return
```

but this returns an error:

```
SyntaxError: [stdin]:7:3: unexpected if
```

Any idea how to properly implement an if statement in coffeescript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was probably an indention error, similar to this one:

[Unexpected 'INDENT' in CoffeeScript Example Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8197466/unexpected-indent-in-coffeescript-example-code)

Consider checking tabs and spaces in your editor.

Comment: You are correct. Just replaced the tab with two spaces and it worked. Thanks a lot.